# change algorithm used by cryptogenj tool

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

i'm using the cryptogen tool in order to create cryptographic artifacts:

```
cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
```

where crypto-config.yaml contains the channel configuration (organizations, peers,...). My question is: there is a way to change the encryption algorithm used by this tool? it generates certificates  using ecdsa-sha256 algorithm in order to produce the private keys. I want to change the algorithm, for example, in dsa. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this from a configuration perspective and no plans to modify it at this point.  I'm the person who actually wrote the tool and it is simply designed to be a basic bootstrap for development and testing purposes.   At this point, ECDSA is really the only tested and supported signature algorithm within Fabric.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Appreciated

Comment: feel free to enter a requirement for this at https://jira.hyperledger.org if you really think we should add this functionality